# How to update data in backend using async functions?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, foreach, promise

I'm working in an audio encoding desktop application where Front end will be sending me the database data called jobdata and i have to update jobdetails object which is present in the array of jobdata which is as follows

```
 "jobId": "dc67b147-754f-48e3-8233-da4aa66913d6",
 "currentLicenseCount": 1,
 "licenseId": "159bb263-b265-451a-ae3d-0d789d586de7",
 "completedAt": 0,
 "reservedLicenseCount": 3,
 "isComplete": false,
 "userId": "5728f50d-146b-47d2-aa7b-a50bc37d641d",
 "updatedAt": 1616999479,
 "jobDetails": [
  {
   "encodingStrength": 0,
   "contentValidation": true,
   "contentFilePath": "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/sample1 (2).mp3",
   "additionalMetadata": {
    "format": {
     "container": "MPEG",
     "duration": 122.12244897959184,
     "codec": "MPEG 1 Layer 3",
     "trackInfo": [],
     "codecProfile": "CBR",
     "numberOfChannels": 2,
     "bitrate": 128000,
     "lossless": false,
     "sampleRate": 44100,
     "tagTypes": [
      "ID3v2.4"
     ]
    },
   "contentSamplingFrequency": 128000,
   "contentFileType": null,
   "contentDescription": null,
   "sonicKey": "fooyGoXpdAf",
   "contentDuration": 122.12244897959184,
   "contentSize": 0,
   "liscenseId": "159bb263-b265-451a-ae3d-0d789d586de7",
   "contentEncoding": null,
   "contentFileName": "sample1 (2).mp3",
   "contentQuality": null,
   "contentType": "MPEG",
   "isComplete": false,
   "fileId": "f6722638-629a-4b88-a3cc-ac5334f762d5"
  },
  {
   "encodingStrength": 0,
   "contentValidation": true,
   "contentFilePath": "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/sample1.mp3",
   "additionalMetadata": {
    "format": {
     "container": "MPEG",
     "duration": 122.12244897959184,
     "codec": "MPEG 1 Layer 3",
     "trackInfo": [],
     "codecProfile": "CBR",
     "numberOfChannels": 2,
     "bitrate": 128000,
     "lossless": false,
     "sampleRate": 44100,
     "tagTypes": [
      "ID3v2.4"
     ]
    },
   "contentSamplingFrequency": 128000,
   "contentFileType": null,
   "contentDescription": null,
   "sonicKey": "8iYrr1p0O3X",
   "contentDuration": 122.12244897959184,
   "contentSize": 0,
   "liscenseId": "159bb263-b265-451a-ae3d-0d789d586de7",
   "contentEncoding": null,
   "contentFileName": "sample1.mp3",
   "contentQuality": null,
   "contentType": "MPEG",
   "isComplete": false,
   "fileId": "05d1be20-f816-438b-8063-da25305459e7"
  },
  {
   "encodingStrength": 0,
   "contentValidation": true,
   "contentFilePath": "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/sample3.mp3",
   "additionalMetadata": {
    "format": {
     "container": "MPEG",
     "duration": 105.82204081632653,
     "codec": "MPEG 1 Layer 3",
     "trackInfo": [],
     "codecProfile": "CBR",
     "numberOfChannels": 2,
     "bitrate": 128000,
     "lossless": false,
     "sampleRate": 44100,
     "tagTypes": [
      "ID3v2.4"
     ]
    },
   "contentSamplingFrequency": 128000,
   "contentFileType": null,
   "contentDescription": null,
   "sonicKey": "uwE4yCM_2YO",
   "contentDuration": 105.82204081632653,
   "contentSize": 0,
   "liscenseId": "159bb263-b265-451a-ae3d-0d789d586de7",
   "contentEncoding": null,
   "contentFileName": "sample3.mp3",
   "contentQuality": null,
   "contentType": "MPEG",
   "isComplete": true,
   "fileId": "15e063ed-8e12-44cd-8674-011e2a189e26"
  }
 ],
 "createdAt": 1616999479,
 "jobName": "meet job 1"
}
```

here it is an array of objects, if the job has 3 files and I have to update the "iscomplete" flag as true and I can't directly put the element as true because there may be multiple file id's ...so i just have to iterate till the length of the array and update "iscomplete" in my backend where ever I find "iscomplete" flag as true in the front end, I have used foreach loop but I don't know why this part doesn't get updated....

```
    //mark file completion and increment the current license count of the job
    var arrayFileData = [];
    arrayFileData = jobData.jobDetails;
    arrayFileData.forEach(function (_value, i) {
      if ((fileId == arrayFileData[i]['fileId'])) {
        arrayFileData[i]['isComplete'] = true;
        jobData['currentLicenseCount'] = jobData['currentLicenseCount'] + 1;
        jobData.jobDetails = arrayFileData;
      }
    });
```

can it be done using async/await or promise?

Comment: can you post the whole foreach block? There are a couple of unknown variables here.

Comment: @IamL  I have written the logic in for each ...which I guess is not working...can it be done in any other way ?

Answer (score 1):

In your forEach function, you didnt destructure it well (you have missed additonalMetadata) thats why this isnt getting updated, correct function will be like this

```
   if ((fileId == arrayFileData[i]['additionalMetadata']['fileId'])) {
     arrayFileData[i]['additionalMetadata']['isComplete'] = true;
     jobData['currentLicenseCount'] = jobData['currentLicenseCount'] + 1;
     jobData.jobDetails = arrayFileData;
   }
 });
```

or you can use more simplified function like

```
let arrayFileData = []
const fileId = '05d1be20-f816-438b-8063-da25305459e7'
arrayFileData = jobData.jobDetails

arrayFileData.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (fileId === item.additionalMetadata.fileId) {
    item.additionalMetadata.isComplete = true
    jobData.currentLicenseCount = jobData.currentLicenseCount + 1
  }
})
```

Also async/await or promise can we used in only asynchronous function and this is a synchronous function, so you cant use async/await or promise in this.

I have attached sample code too and updated one of the fileId, you can have a look at it too.

```js
const jobData = {
  jobId: 'dc67b147-754f-48e3-8233-da4aa66913d6',
  currentLicenseCount: 1,
  licenseId: '159bb263-b265-451a-ae3d-0d789d586de7',
  completedAt: 0,
  reservedLicenseCount: 3,
  isComplete: false,
  userId: '5728f50d-146b-47d2-aa7b-a50bc37d641d',
  updatedAt: 1616999479,
  jobDetails: [
    {
      encodingStrength: 0,
      contentValidation: true,
      contentFilePath: '/home/ubuntu/Downloads/sample1 (2).mp3',
      additionalMetadata: {
        format: {
          container: 'MPEG',
          duration: 122.12244897959184,
          codec: 'MPEG 1 Layer 3',
          trackInfo: [],
          codecProfile: 'CBR',
          numberOfChannels: 2,
          bitrate: 128000,
          lossless: false,
          sampleRate: 44100,
          tagTypes: ['ID3v2.4'],
        },
        contentSamplingFrequency: 128000,
        contentFileType: null,
        contentDescription: null,
        sonicKey: 'fooyGoXpdAf',
        contentDuration: 122.12244897959184,
        contentSize: 0,
        liscenseId: '159bb263-b265-451a-ae3d-0d789d586de7',
        contentEncoding: null,
        contentFileName: 'sample1 (2).mp3',
        contentQuality: null,
        contentType: 'MPEG',
        isComplete: false,
        fileId: 'f6722638-629a-4b88-a3cc-ac5334f762d5',
      },
    },
    {
      encodingStrength: 0,
      contentValidation: true,
      contentFilePath: '/home/ubuntu/Downloads/sample1.mp3',
      additionalMetadata: {
        format: {
          container: 'MPEG',
          duration: 122.12244897959184,
          codec: 'MPEG 1 Layer 3',
          trackInfo: [],
          codecProfile: 'CBR',
          numberOfChannels: 2,
          bitrate: 128000,
          lossless: false,
          sampleRate: 44100,
          tagTypes: ['ID3v2.4'],
        },
        contentSamplingFrequency: 128000,
        contentFileType: null,
        contentDescription: null,
        sonicKey: '8iYrr1p0O3X',
        contentDuration: 122.12244897959184,
        contentSize: 0,
        liscenseId: '159bb263-b265-451a-ae3d-0d789d586de7',
        contentEncoding: null,
        contentFileName: 'sample1.mp3',
        contentQuality: null,
        contentType: 'MPEG',
        isComplete: false,
        fileId: '05d1be20-f816-438b-8063-da25305459e7',
      },
    },
    {
      encodingStrength: 0,
      contentValidation: true,
      contentFilePath: '/home/ubuntu/Downloads/sample3.mp3',
      additionalMetadata: {
        format: {
          container: 'MPEG',
          duration: 105.82204081632653,
          codec: 'MPEG 1 Layer 3',
          trackInfo: [],
          codecProfile: 'CBR',
          numberOfChannels: 2,
          bitrate: 128000,
          lossless: false,
          sampleRate: 44100,
          tagTypes: ['ID3v2.4'],
        },
        contentSamplingFrequency: 128000,
        contentFileType: null,
        contentDescription: null,
        sonicKey: 'uwE4yCM_2YO',
        contentDuration: 105.82204081632653,
        contentSize: 0,
        liscenseId: '159bb263-b265-451a-ae3d-0d789d586de7',
        contentEncoding: null,
        contentFileName: 'sample3.mp3',
        contentQuality: null,
        contentType: 'MPEG',
        isComplete: true,
        fileId: '15e063ed-8e12-44cd-8674-011e2a189e26',
      },
    },
  ],
  createdAt: 1616999479,
  jobName: 'meet job 1',
}

//mark file completion and increment the current license count of the job
let arrayFileData = []
const fileId = '05d1be20-f816-438b-8063-da25305459e7'
//Added a constant ID, can assume it as a frontend request
arrayFileData = jobData.jobDetails

arrayFileData.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (fileId === item.additionalMetadata.fileId) {
    item.additionalMetadata.isComplete = true
    jobData.currentLicenseCount = jobData.currentLicenseCount + 1
  }
})

console.log('Job Data :', jobData)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but not only "iscomplete" if there are multiple keys which must be updated, and here we can't specify where what changes must be done because whatever front end sends that fields must be updated by the backend also, it would be helpful if you can help me relate with this. Can we use any other array functions?

Comment: only fields inside "jobDetails" needs to be updated or anything from "jobData"? Also if possible just give me sample request like what fields need to be updated, that will help me to understand the requirement.

Comment: no no...only fields inside "Job Details" ...here without specifying particular key value pair...like we are specifying that update iscomplete flag but what if not only iscomplete but more than one key value pairs...Because sometimes whatever the front end sends it may be completely a black box for backend but we have to update the job details even in the back end so that the end user details are displayed correct from the backend  to the front end...

Comment: can you share one of the sample request that you will get from frontend, so i can answer you in a better you, right now its really vast and i also dont know the format frontend will be sending like keys and values. So a sample request will really help me.